# Groovy Mock the same Stream call more than one time

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, spock

Has problem :

```
given:
someService.getSome(*_) >> Stream.of("A", "B")
when:
someService.getSomeMethod()
then:
noExceptionThrown()
```

Error:
"stream has already been operated upon or closed"

in method "getSomeMethod()" few times are calling someService.getSome(*_) which has to return the same stream.
Can somebody help with this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to return *the same Stream*, since you can only process each one once. Instead, return *identical copies of the Stream*:

```
someService.getSome(*_) >> { Stream.of("A", "B") }
```

(It's probably also a good idea to be more specific about your expected arguments rather than using `*_`.)

Comment: How to return identical copies of the Stream? can you give me any examples?
someService.getSome(1L, List.of("11111", "2222222")) and the same values has getSomeMethod()

Comment: @DovileBarkauskaite I showed you exactly how to do it—you use a closure instead of an immediate value.

Comment: Yes you are right thank you very much these {} make a copy

Comment: @DovileBarkauskaite If this answer solves your problem, you can "accept" it (mark it correct) by clicking on the green check mark to the left.